# CSS inheritance without modifying HTML

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following foo class

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">..</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo{
  ..some styles here...
}
```

Now I want to add a div with class bar that uses foo's styling:

```
<div class="bar foo">..</div>
```

But this involves changing the HTML. Is there a way to inherit the styling of another class without changing the HTML?

Something like:

```
<div class="bar">..</div>

.bar{
  inherit: .foo;
 }
```

Comment: Have you looked at LESS?

Comment: Now, *that* looks interesting.

Comment: You could use JS. I'm writing a solution right now. Unfortunately, less involves child elements; unless you need to establish some kind of parent-child inheritance, it won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no selector that allows inheritance of CSS properties. If you do not want to directly change your HTML code, you could add a small JavaScript command like so:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){x[i].setAttribute("class","foo bar");}
```

(This will change all of the `foo` class divs into `foo bar` class divs. If you want to change specific divs, use this command: `document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[n].setAttribute("class","foo bar");`, where `n` is the index of the `foo` class div.)

Otherwise, without using JavaScript, there is no way to "inherit" the CSS classes, unfortunately.

Comment: I used this approach because in my case,    the css for `foo` comes from another CSS files, so using a simple solution like Zach's would involve changing other files which might end up in a messy technical debt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.foo, .bar
{
    /* rules that two classes have in common */
}

.foo
{
    /* rules that apply to the foo class only */
}

.bar
{
    /* rules that apply to the bar class only */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By applying LESS, you can mix in declarations like this:

```css
/* LESS */
.foo {
  /* some style here */
}

.bar {
  .foo;
}
```

Note here if you want to hide ruleset `.foo` (probably a ruleset only for inheritance use) from the CSS output, you can modify the code above a little:

```css
/* LESS */
.foo() { /* It's called "parametric mixin" */
  /* some style here */
}

.bar {
  .foo;
}
```

By using LESS (or SASS/Stylus if you like) you can decouple styles and class names in your HTML code while keeping style rulesets reusable:

```html
<!-- no need to use style-related class name here -->
<h2 class="post-title">...</h2>
```

```css
/* LESS */
/* reusable style ruleset */
.bold-title() {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
}

/* actually use those rulesets */
.post-title {
  .bold-title;
}
```

And after compilation you will get neat CSS code like this:

```css
/* CSS */
.post-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no inherit option in css. you can add you .bar class aftre the .foo class separated by a  comma(,)

```
.bar, .foo{
  ..some styles here...
}
```